# How to convert 600 MB PDF to MS Word Doc?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

All the apps, online & offline, do not seem to support such a filesize.

Anyone out there have experience of succeeding for large PDFs?

Comment: How does the PDF come along? it could be a single page document, heavy on images, but it could also be a text document containing thousands of pages… I would not be surprised when, even if you could create the .docx document, Word would choke on it.

Comment: Its made up of scanned jpgs

Comment: Yikes… So, first you will need to OCR the document; of the desktop software available, Abbyy Finereader is considered as a leading product, and it should be able to create a Word format directly.

Comment: Adobe Acrobat has the capability to convert a PDF into a Word document.  I see no reason it would have a problem with a file this small, at least I consider it small, I deal PDF and Word documents much larger daily.

Comment: Does your file really have that much content, or is it just poorly compressed? If it's only a few images that aren't that big, you can probably optimize the PDF first to reduce the size.

Comment: Its from full page A4 jpg scans of a text archive

Answer (score 0):

There are some free tools that help you split big PDFs into smaller documents. For example PDFSAM http://www.pdfsam.org/ lets you split long documents up into smaller parts. Maybe then you can feel the smaller documents into Word?

Answer (score 0):

Try some command line tools, like `oowriter`/`swriter` (it require libre/openoffice suite installed).

Here is example to convert DOC int PDF:

```
oowriter -pt pdf file.doc
```

or:

```
oowriter -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export file.doc –
```

so to do opposite I believe it should be straight forward.

See: [convert .doc files to .pdf file using imagemagick](https://askubuntu.com/q/171218/78223) at AskUbuntu

---

Other tool to consider is `unoconvd`, e.g.:

```
unoconv --format pdf --output /OUTPUT_DIR/ file.odt
```

See: [Converting documents (ODT, DOC to PDF) on PHP with Unoconv / LibreOffice](http://tech.rgou.net/en/php/converting-documents-odt-doc-to-pdf-on-php-with-unoconv-libreoffice/)

---

Or [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) tools, however you can convert it only to separate image files (e.g. `convert doc.pdf doc.png`), however I'm not sure about ODT/RTF/DOC formats.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://www.pdf2word.io/? Its my favourite tool to convert PDF to .doc.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for your contribution. Please read [How do I recommend software in my answers?](//meta.superuser.com/a/5330) paying particular attention to the items in `bold`. After doing so, please [edit your answer](//superuser.com/posts/1348543/edit) so it follows the guidelines. It might also be a good idea to take the [Tour] and read the [Ask] and [Answer] pages to learn how this site works.